# Turn private variable to public in runtime?

Tags: vb.net, variables, object, components, windows-forms-designer

please see image attached. [image]

i want it to be

```
Public components As System.ComponentModel.lContainer
```

but every time I edit the form design, it always change back to its original code

```
Private components As System.ComponentModel.lContainer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a public Property in your class that returns a private member, like yours. This code is generated by form designer and probably you can not change the behavior of this. Even if you could, I wouldn't suggest you to do this.

```
Public Class MyForm

    Public Property Container As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

        Get

            Return Me.components

        End Get

    End Property

End Class
```

Cheers